# Facebook APP for registration, submission without publishing everything on our website

Tags: facebook, registration, submission

I'm trying to add a "Register with Facebook"-button on our website, and I want this button to have the user_birthday privilige.

Simply put, our service requires the users birthday.

So, I we need our APP to clear submission.

Problem is that the Facebook team wants to use the APP in order to approve it. (Of course they do). But we do not want to add a broken "Register with Facebook"-button to our website. (It's broken as long as we don't have the birthday privilige).

There must be someone else who've faced this problem. Is it possible to direct the Facebook team to our test server? Which is located on another URL. Having a broken button on our website for up to seven days makes no sense..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 0):

I received this answer from David Doyle on Facebook:

"You can direct us to a test server or staging area and we'd be happy to review from there. 
Just be sure to provide any login credentials in your review instructions.

Most developers start their review instructions with a note that says "please find our staging area here " that might be easier for you than changing your app settings."

Good enough for me! :-)

https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/718033091573541/